# Hide BitLocker "Unlock Drive" Notifications in Windows 10?

Tags: encryption, windows-10, notifications, bitlocker, notification-area

In Windows 10, when you mount an BitLocker encrypted drive (vhd in my case), Windows issues a notification prompting you to unlock the drive. Is there a way to turn off this particular notification? It's a system notification so you can't do the normal thing where you'd toggle "turn off notifications for this app".

Alternatively, is there any API that would let me programmatically dismiss this notification while keep notifications from other apps?

Answer (score 0):

I don't believe there is a way to disable the system popups (other than registry hacks)

You can have the Drive automatically unlock, and there will not be a popup?

Not quite the answer you were probably looking for, but it does stop the popup.

[image]

Just click more options, then check the box for Auto unlock.

It works for me on a removable drive, couldn't try with a VHD.